# Bad performance on a sorting request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very simple query in a NodeJS / Mongoose application:

```
const blocks = await Block
  .find({
    content: ObjectId(internalId),
  })
  .sort({ position: 1, _id: 1 })
```

with the schema:

```
const BlockSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  (...)
  content: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Domain',
    index: true
  },
  concept: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ConceptDetails',
    index: true
  },
  conceptDetails: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'ConceptDetails',
    index: true
  },
  creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});


const Block = mongoose.model(
  'Block',
  BlockSchema
);
```

The performance of this simple query was really bad with real data (around 900ms) so I added the following index:

```
db.blocks.createIndex({ position: 1, _id: 1 });
```

It improves the performance (around 330ms) but I expected to have something better for a request like that. FYI I have 13100 block items in the database.

Is there something else I can do to improve performance?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a find clause to filter by `content`. This makes the index not usable. You can check this with explain(). Below is a visualization of the query plan on my local replication of your scenario. You can see `COLLSCAN`, which indicates the index is not used.
[image]

---

## What can we do?

We can build another compound index, which includes the field `content` to speed up the query. Make sure `content` is before the your sort fields `position` and `_id` so the index can be utilized

```js
db.collection.createIndex({content: 1, position: 1, _id: 1 })
```

You can check again the query plan:
[image]
You can see the query plan changed to `IXSCAN`, which utilized the new index. You can then expect a faster query benefit from index scan.

You can check out [this official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#query-optimization) for more details on query coverage and optimization.